# How to add a 6 px red border to a bootstrap modal?

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I have my bootstrap modal  working. However I want to add a sort of frame of 6 px solid red. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

**css**

```
.modal-content{
  border:red 6px solid;
}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6aqn4fw/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your **CSS** or **Style tag**:

```
.modal-content{

  border:red 6px solid;

}
```

Or

you can add inline style:

```
<div class="modal-content" style="border: red 6px solid;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
   .modal-content{          
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

Comment: Oops seems like someone else answered it as i was typing.